# Export an AM Stock chart

Tags: amcharts

Is there a way to enable exporting for a Stockchart? I know it is doable for a normal chart, but for a stock chart, I am getting undefined when try to enable the export mode,

I have tried: `chart.export.enabled=true;` and `chart.amExport.enabled = true;` and

```
var amExport = new AmCharts.AmExport();
amExport.enabled = true;
chart.export=amExport;
```

but all failed.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use the new initialization style of amCharts. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28598274/what-is-difference-between-amcharts-makechart-and-new-amcharts-amserialchart/28607107#28607107) to a question related to this.
It seems like the old approach you tried is not working anymore. (At least my few tests were not running)
To enable the export use this in the initialization code:

```
export: {
    enabled: true,
    position: "bottom-right"
}
```

And don't forget to include the needed export plugin!

A tutorial can be found [here](http://www.amcharts.com/categories/all-types/).

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2hjwyt72/1/).

---

**Update:**

Ok, so this took me a bit, but i found a way, how you can the export feature dynamically. (With JS or JSON initialization)

```
chart.export = {
    enabled: true,
    position: "bottom-right"
}
chart.initHC = false;
chart.validateNow();
```

The key is to set `initHC` to false, because else it wont load the handler for the plugin. Then just validate again, add some pixie dust and tadaa - it works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the links above are for normal am charts and not stock charts, also I cant use the JSON initialization because i already set a lot of properties of the chart using javascript initialzation.

Comment: Sry but this is wrong. The tutorials says the plugin works with AmStock too and the fiddle is clearly a stock chart. And i would really recommend you to switch to the JSON initialization. It's so much better.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I got it to work by using the JSON notification initialization just before your update on the answer, and it worked. Also you were right, the example was about a stock chart, :).  I will also test the JS initialzation and let you know. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above response to include the correct plugins, please ensure you are using html color codes such as "#FF0000" instead of "red" which is supported by earlier am chart export versions if you specify your own colors in the graph (graph.useDataSetColors = false) and valueaxis.

Export works fine whether you use the new JSON or the old style (I am still using the old style new AmCharts.AmStockChart() and  $scope.chart.write("chartdiv");