# How can i disable my title in amcharts from beginning on loading?

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, amcharts

I am using `amcharts` to prepare graph for 5 application status. On clicking each title, respective application column appears and on clicking again title disables and column for that application disappears. How can I keep this title disable from the beginning on load.

```
function createXYZchart() {
    var chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
    chart.dataProvider = dataXYZ; //data source
    chart.categoryField = "month"; //data provider X-Axis

    var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
    categoryAxis.labelRotation = 90;
    chart.angle = 60;
    chart.depth3D = 5;
    chart.columnWidth = 0.85;

    var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
    valueAxis.dashLength = 10;
    valueAxis.autoGridCount = false;
    valueAxis.minimum = 90;
    valueAxis.maximum = 100;
    valueAxis.gridCount=5;
    valueAxis.labelFunction = formatLabel;
    chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);
}
```

Comment: I would highly recommend you to initialize your chart using the JSON Format. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28598274/what-is-difference-between-amcharts-makechart-and-new-amcharts-amserialchart/28607107#28607107) related to this.

Comment: Could you prepare a fiddle please, with what you achieved already? Your code is just basic initialization.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the graph on initial chart load, set it's [`hidden`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#hidden) attribute to `true`.

I.e.:

```
var graph = new AmChars.AmGraph();
graph.hidden = true;
graph.title = "Hidden graph";
graph.valueField = "value";
chart.addGraph(graph);
```