# AmCharts Line chart disconnected from Axis

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, amcharts

My graph is disconnected from my y-axis on creation. I was wondering if anyone had the same problem? I tried playing with the axis-offset as you can see. does not fix the problem.

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlVj2.jpg)

[image]

```
            AmCharts.ready(function () {
            chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
            chart.dataProvider = chartData;
            chart.categoryField = "timestamp";
            chart.startDuration = 0;
            chart.pathToImages = "/design/javascripts/amcharts/images/";
            chart.zoomOutButton = {

            var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
            valueAxis.title = "{t}Impressions{/t}";
            valueAxis.offset = -25;
            valueAxis.stackType = "regular";
            valueAxis.position = "left";
            valueAxis.gridAlpha = 0.1;
            valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0.2;
            valueAxis.dashLength = 1;
            chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);
                backgroundColor: '#000000',
                backgroundAlpha: 0.15
            };
```

Please help

Comment: Please consider using the JSON style to initialize your chart. It's far better write- and readable. [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28598274/what-is-difference-between-amcharts-makechart-and-new-amcharts-amserialchart/28607107#28607107)

Comment: Btw welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please add your `chartData`? It seems like you have a datapoint just before your first values occur.  Maybe prepare a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Oh and please fix the `zoomOutButton` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `startOnAxis` property of the `categoryAxis` object to `true`

```
chart.categoryAxis.startOnAxis = true;
```

http://docs.amcharts.com/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis

EDIT:
As [martynasma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634045/martynasma) suggested, you should note that this won't work if you have `chart.categoryAxis.parseDates` set to `true` unless you also set `chart.categoryAxis.equalSpacing` to `true`. As stated on the amcharts CategoryAxis documentation about "startOnAxis" property:

> Specifies whether the graph should start on axis or not. In case you display columns, it is recommended to set this to false. If parseDates is set to true, startOnAxis will allways be false, unless equalSpacing is set to true.

Comment: Correct about `startOnAxis`. However this might not work if you are using date-based category axis (which is not clear because requester did not post full code). In order for that to work, you would also need to set `chart.categoryAxis.equalSpacing = true` (http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#equalSpacing) I suggest you update your answer accoridngly.

Comment: @martynasma and Diego you are awesome! Thanks to you i was able to fix my graph! #allTheLove