# Amcharts unable to cover full width

Tags: reactjs, amcharts4

I have the same problem as the OP in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32313630/amcharts-line-chart-disconnected-from-axis) but the solution didn't solve my problem.  Here's my code:

```
const dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
    dateAxis.dataFields.category = 'timestamp';
    dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
    dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
    dateAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;
    dateAxis.baseInterval = { count: 1, timeUnit: 'day' };
    dateAxis.renderer.labels.template.fill = am4core.color('rgba(255, 255, 255, .4)');
    dateAxis.startOnAxis = true;
    dateAxis.equalSpacing = true;
    this.setState(() => ({ dateAxis }));*emphasized text*

   const createSeries = (field, name, stacked, fillColor, strokeColor) => {
      const series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
      series.xAxis.width = am4core.percent(100);
...
```

This is what the chart looks like now:
[image]

I want the lines to fill the entire width of the chart. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, the example you linked to is for AmCharts v3, which is completely different from v4 (the version you're using).

You need to adjust the [`startLocation`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/axis/#startLocation_property) and [`endLocation`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/axis/#endLocation_property) of the axis to control how much of the cells are visible in order to make the lines/filled area reach the ends of the axis as described in [this tutorial](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/positioning-axis-elements/#Setting_where_axis_starts_and_ends). Setting both values to .5 should be sufficient:

```
dateAxis.startLocation = 0.5;
dateAxis.endLocation = 0.5;
```

This is also demonstrated in [this stacked area chart demo](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/stacked-area/). A trimmed down version of this is reproduced below:

```js
// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

chart.data = [{
  "year": "1994",
  "cars": 1587,
  "motorcycles": 650,
  "bicycles": 121
}, {
  "year": "1995",
  "cars": 1567,
  "motorcycles": 683,
  "bicycles": 146
}, {
  "year": "1996",
  "cars": 1617,
  "motorcycles": 691,
  "bicycles": 138
}, {
  "year": "1997",
  "cars": 1630,
  "motorcycles": 642,
  "bicycles": 127
}, {
  "year": "1998",
  "cars": 1660,
  "motorcycles": 699,
  "bicycles": 105
}, {
  "year": "1999",
  "cars": 1683,
  "motorcycles": 721,
  "bicycles": 109
}, {
  "year": "2000",
  "cars": 1691,
  "motorcycles": 737,
  "bicycles": 112
}, {
  "year": "2001",
  "cars": 1298,
  "motorcycles": 680,
  "bicycles": 101
}, {
  "year": "2002",
  "cars": 1275,
  "motorcycles": 664,
  "bicycles": 97
}, {
  "year": "2003",
  "cars": 1246,
  "motorcycles": 648,
  "bicycles": 93
}, {
  "year": "2004",
  "cars": 1318,
  "motorcycles": 697,
  "bicycles": 111
}, {
  "year": "2005",
  "cars": 1213,
  "motorcycles": 633,
  "bicycles": 87
}, {
  "year": "2006",
  "cars": 1199,
  "motorcycles": 621,
  "bicycles": 79
}, {
  "year": "2007",
  "cars": 1110,
  "motorcycles": 210,
  "bicycles": 81
}, {
  "year": "2008",
  "cars": 1165,
  "motorcycles": 232,
  "bicycles": 75
}, {
  "year": "2009",
  "cars": 1145,
  "motorcycles": 219,
  "bicycles": 88
}, {
  "year": "2010",
  "cars": 1163,
  "motorcycles": 201,
  "bicycles": 82
}, {
  "year": "2011",
  "cars": 1180,
  "motorcycles": 285,
  "bicycles": 87
}, {
  "year": "2012",
  "cars": 1159,
  "motorcycles": 277,
  "bicycles": 71
}];

chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "yyyy";
var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 60;
dateAxis.startLocation = 0.5;
dateAxis.endLocation = 0.5;
dateAxis.baseInterval = {
  timeUnit: "year",
  count: 1
}

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;

var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.dateX = "year";
series.name = "cars";
series.dataFields.valueY = "cars";
series.tooltipHTML = "<img src='https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/car.png' style='vertical-align:bottom; margin-right: 10px; width:28px; height:21px;'><span style='font-size:14px; color:#000000;'><b>{valueY.value}</b></span>";
series.tooltipText = "[#000]{valueY.value}[/]";
series.tooltip.background.fill = am4core.color("#FFF");
series.tooltip.getStrokeFromObject = true;
series.tooltip.background.strokeWidth = 3;
series.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
series.fillOpacity = 0.6;
series.strokeWidth = 2;
series.stacked = true;

var series2 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series2.name = "motorcycles";
series2.dataFields.dateX = "year";
series2.dataFields.valueY = "motorcycles";
series2.tooltipHTML = "<img src='https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/motorcycle.png' style='vertical-align:bottom; margin-right: 10px; width:28px; height:21px;'><span style='font-size:14px; color:#000000;'><b>{valueY.value}</b></span>";
series2.tooltipText = "[#000]{valueY.value}[/]";
series2.tooltip.background.fill = am4core.color("#FFF");
series2.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
series2.tooltip.getStrokeFromObject = true;
series2.tooltip.background.strokeWidth = 3;
series2.sequencedInterpolation = true;
series2.fillOpacity = 0.6;
series2.stacked = true;
series2.strokeWidth = 2;

var series3 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series3.name = "bicycles";
series3.dataFields.dateX = "year";
series3.dataFields.valueY = "bicycles";
series3.tooltipHTML = "<img src='https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/bicycle.png' style='vertical-align:bottom; margin-right: 10px; width:28px; height:21px;'><span style='font-size:14px; color:#000000;'><b>{valueY.value}</b></span>";
series3.tooltipText = "[#000]{valueY.value}[/]";
series3.tooltip.background.fill = am4core.color("#FFF");
series3.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
series3.tooltip.getStrokeFromObject = true;
series3.tooltip.background.strokeWidth = 3;
series3.sequencedInterpolation = true;
series3.fillOpacity = 0.6;
series3.defaultState.transitionDuration = 1000;
series3.stacked = true;
series3.strokeWidth = 2;
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```