# Amcharts - how to format valueField inside custom tooltip?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I've got a basic AmGraph:

```
    graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();

    graph.lineThickness = 4;
    graph.valueAxis = valueAxis;
    graph.fillAlphas = 0;
    graph.valueAxis = valueAxis;
    graph.valueAxis.minimum = 0;

    graph.title = "likes";
    graph.labelText = " ";
    graph.valueField = "likes_1";
```

The problem is that the numberFormatter doesn't format values if I'm using a custom balloonText function:

```
    graph.numberFormatter = {precision: -1, decimalSeparator:",", thousandsSeparator:","};
```

So if I use this:

```
    graph.balloonText = "<b>got: [[likes_1]] </b>";
```

The tooltip looks like this:

```
   "got: 1000"
```

How can I format the value? if I try to use javascript for formatting it (Numeral.js):

```
    graph.balloonText = "<script>numeral( [[likes_1]] ).format("0,0") </script>";
```

The wildcard isn't replaced with the actual value when building the page (but rather when hovering the chart?), so I just get:

```
    Uncaught ReferenceError: likes_32 is not defined
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (First I highly recommend to use the newer way of chart
>   initialization! Look
>   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28598274/what-is-difference-between-amcharts-makechart-and-new-amcharts-amserialchart/28607107#28607107)
>   for that.)

Instead of `balloonText` you can use [`balloonFunction`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#balloonFunction), which allows you to change the text with JavaScript. Inside there you can format the number according to your wishes.
I prepared a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pzfu2kpz/) using the [`AmCharts.formatNumber`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmCharts#formatNumber) formatter.

```
return AmCharts.formatNumber(graphDataItem.values.value, {
        precision: -1,
        decimalSeparator: '.',
        thousandsSeparator: ','
    }, -1);
```

You can still use `Numeral.js` in there though (it's syntax seems a little more straight forward to me).

```
return numeral(graphDataItem.values.value).format("0,0");
```

Comment: Can I send any parameters to the balloonFunction callback? because my chartData is designed for multiple graphs, and each graph has a different tooltip, along with a different valueField. Or I could just build different callbacks for each graph?

        graph.valueField = "likes_1";

        graph2.valueField = "likes_2";

Comment: As the `balloonFunction` is part of the `graph` object, each graph can have a different implementation for formatting (or whatever you want to do with the tooltip content). You just have to return a valid string, the content doesn't matter. You can easily debug the function to see what information is provided through the arguments.

Comment: Thank you, it has. It's VERY ugly, as I have one chart and 40 or more graphs, so 40 or more formatting functions (10+ for each of the 4 toggle views), but it works. I'll play with a javascript hashmap that holds all the data and allows me to access it from the same function with some parameters.. if I'm ever out of stuff to do :)

Comment: You can define the function once and just reference it in the configuration. Look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pzfu2kpz/1/).

Comment: I know, thanks. It's a little more tricky, because I'm using smarty to build the chartdata, make the graphs access it (setting various fields as the valueFields) and the formatting functions...